# How to create wallet with web3j and web3swift like with web3js web3.eth.accounts.create(); function?

Tags: web3js, web3j, ios

With web3js v1.0.0 you can create accounts with `web3.eth.accounts.create();` and access the public address and private key with `newWallet.address` and `newWallet.privateKey`.

How can you do this with web3j or web3Swift.

The documentation is difficult to find this in.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you solve it? Is my answer helps?

Answer (score 0):

Here we go, by using [web3swift](https://github.com/matterinc/web3swift) library:

#### Create Account

```
    // Create keystore and account with password.    
    let keystore = try! EthereumKeystoreV3(password: "changeme"); // generates a private key internally if node "privateKey" parameter supplied
    let account = keystore!.addresses![0]
    print(account)
```

---

We are also working on unification of the API format. I already open issue to cover your need in the quesiton: https://github.com/matterinc/web3swift/issues/40

Here a usage example for the next major update of the library:

```
newWallet = web3.eth.accounts.create() 
// access the public address 
newWallet.address
//private key:
newWallet.privateKey
```